# Can modern CSS display/hide N children items from X by random?

Tags: css

Say I have X items in a `<ul>` DOM:

```
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  ...
  <li>X</li>
<ul>
```

It's easy to do this with JavaScript but is it possible to only display N items by random with pure CSS commands?

For "display", I mean the opposite of `display:none`. So there are `X-N` items be regarded as `display:none`

Comment: There's no randomiser logic in CSS. The biggest stumbling block is determining the point at which a random function should be evaluated.

Comment: Not gonna help OP, but your comment @Alohci made me want to try, and actually there is now somewhat of a bit of entropy possible in CSS+HTML: https://jsfiddle.net/4ty208ed/ (Test in Chrome, Firefox doesn't seem to block painting while fetching resources).

Comment: @Kaiido The jsfiddle demo works interestingly.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with only CSS because it will require some programming, and CSS is not a programming language.

You can do this with Javascript and CSS as follows:

```
const items = document.querySelectorAll("li");
const numberToShow = Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length);

for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  if (i < numberToShow) {
    items[i].style.display = "block";
  } else {
    items[i].style.display = "none";
  }
}
```